# SQL IN query behavior

Tags: mysql

Executing the following SQL statement;

`select  '2312' in ('2312,254,2111') as result1, 2312 in ('2312,254,2111') as result2`

I am getting the following result

```
+---------+---------+
| result1 | result2 |
+---------+---------+
|       0 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

I would expect the opposite result. Having `result1` to be `true` and `result2` to be `false`. Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using IN() with a CSV-string as parameter is not supported.

It should be `IN ('2312','254','2111')` instead of `IN ('2312,254,2111')`

The reason for the observed behaviour is the implicit type conversion from string to integer that is happening here.

Observe:

```
SELECT 2312 IN ('2312,254,2111') -- result: 1
SELECT 2312 IN ('254,2312,2111') -- result: 0 -- interesting
SELECT 2312 = '2312,254,2111'    -- result: 1 << see ??
SELECT 2312 = '254,2312,2111'    -- result: 0
```

Only the first number in the string is relevant. The rest is ignored due to the implicit type conversion.

Also,

```
SELECT '2312' in ('2312,254,2111') -- result: 0
```

is false, because no type conversion happens here. '2312' does not equal the only string '2312,254,2111' in the value list and hence the IN() operator return false.

If you use a list of values for IN() instead of a CSV-string, everything works als expected:

```
SELECT
   2312  IN ('2312','254','2111')  -- result: 1
, '2312' IN ('2312','254','2111')  -- result: 1
,  254   IN ('2312','254','2111')  -- result: 1
, '254'  IN ('2312','254','2111')  -- result: 1
,  2312  IN (2312,254,2111)        -- result: 1
, '2312' IN (2312,254,2111)        -- result: 1
,  254   IN (2312,254,2111)        -- result: 1
, '254'  IN (2312,254,2111)        -- result: 1
```

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in):

> Implicit type conversion may produce nonintuitive results:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 'a' IN (0), 0 IN ('b');
>         -> 1, 1
> ```
>
> In both cases, the comparison values are converted to floating-point values, yielding 0.0 in each case, and a comparison result of 1 (true).

Comment: Yes, when comparing in an integer context, a string like `'2312,254,2111'` is cast to its integer value, which is based on any leading digits, and ignores subsequent characters like the `,` and anything that follows. Whereas comparing it to a string `'2312'` is a string-to-string comparison, so it compares the whole string verbatim.